# pytest behaves strangely with optional parameter

Tags: python, pytest

What does pytest *actually* do when it invokes a function for testing, particularly if the function being tested has an optional parameter?

See the simple code below.

```
import pytest

def foo(ans = [ ]):
    ans.append(1)
    ans.append(2)
    ans.append(3)

    return ans 

def test_foo():
    x = foo()
    assert x == [1, 2, 3]

pytest.main(["-v"])
```

When this code is run, pytest reports this error:

```
    def test_foo():
        x = foo()
>       assert x == [1, 2, 3]
E       assert [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]
E         Left contains 3 more items, first extra item: 1
E         Full diff:
E         - [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
E         + [1, 2, 3]
```

The error suggests that pytest invokes the function being tested twice, somehow passing the optional parameter back into the function!

Note that if I make a small change to the code, the test succeeds:

```
def foo(ans = [ ]):
    ans = [ ]
    ans.append(1)
    ans.append(2)
    ans.append(3)

    return ans
```

Comment: Lol. I suggest that pytest has done its job perfectly but in an unexpected way. It's thrown up an issue before it bites you in your actual code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `pytest`, just don't use mutables in defaults. Try calling `print(foo())` multiple times in the interactive shell to verify.